# Map the values on pandas dataframe using the values on the corresponding index in a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to map this DataFrame:

```
   one  three  two
A    4      1    2
B    1      2    1
C    2    NaN    2
D    3      3    3
```

to another one so that the values in the new one are taken from a list that uses the old values as indexes: `[2.0, 3.6666666666666665, 5.333333333333333, 7.0]`. I need an elegant solution, the ugly solution would be to do this element wise using for loops.

Here is the starter code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'three': {'A': 1.0, 'C': nan, 'B': 2.0, 'D': 3.0}, 'two': {'A': 2.0, 'C': 2.0, 'B': 1.0, 'D': 3.0}, 'one': {'A': 4.0, 'C': 2.0, 'B': 1.0, 'D': 3.0}}
l = [2.0, 3.6666666666666665, 5.333333333333333, 7.0]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

What I was trying was this:

```
conv = lambda x: l[int(x)-1] if x<>'NaN' else 'NaN'
df2 = df.applymap(conv)
```

unfortunately x is the whole column. Is it possible to get the current row index when using applymap() or apply()?

A second possibility would be done in df.values and probably use some functional programming in numpy to broadcast values.. as referenced [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.functional.html) but I am not such a great numpy maestro.

Right now I do this, and it works but it is ugly as hell:

```
d = df.to_dict()
d2 = {}

for c in d:
    t = {}
    for r in d[c]:
        v = d[c][r]
        try:
            t[r] = l[int(v)-1]
        except:
            t[r]=None
    d2[c] = t

df = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the DataFrame's [`replace()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method to do this.

Just pass in two lists: the values to find and the values to swap them for:

```
>>> find = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> repl = [2.0, 3.6666666666666665, 5.333333333333333, 7.0]
>>> df.replace(find, repl)
        one     three       two
A  7.000000  2.000000  3.666667
B  2.000000  3.666667  2.000000
C  3.666667       NaN  3.666667
D  5.333333  5.333333  5.333333
```

Comment: @grokkaine Just out of curiosity, did this answer your question satisfactorily? If not I can adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which might be more efficient if the list is large (not tested)

```
repl = [2.0, 3.6666666666666665, 5.333333333333333, 7.0]
(df-1).map(repl.__getitem__)
```

This is for 1-based indices, if 0-based replace `(df-1)` with just `df`